# CMake: Generate Unix Makefiles which ignore errors

Tags: makefile, cmake

In Unix Makefile I can prefix a recipe line with `-` to ignore any error that will occur (as describe in [Errors in Recipes](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Errors-in-Recipes)).

```
hello_world: hello_world.cxx
    -$(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $^ -o $@
```

I converted my Makefile to CMake:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)
project(HelloWorld)

add_executable(hello_world hello_world.cxx)
```

and run `cmake` and the generated Makefile looking fine, except the missing `-`.

Is it possible to generate Unix Makefile with CMake that will ignore errors (prefix the recipe line with `-`)?
The best would be to specify it per target level. I know I can run `make -i` to have the same behaviour but it isn't that convenient.

Comment: But if the compiler reports the error, resulted executable won't be created. What is a use case of the behavior which you want?

Comment: @Tsyvarev I have a collection of code examples: Some purposefully show compiler errors. So when a person compiles all examples I don't want to stop the whole process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot.

`make` is designed to give the user a fine control over commands it runs. `CMake`'s under-the-hood commands are supposed to always succeed.

As a hack, you can generate makefiles and run `make --ignore-errors`.

But I advice making each of your examples that would fail a separate project, and run them from an external script.